# Incrementing and decrementing value of price

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I like to implement the on-time changing on price when the user changes or updates the quantity. I am having an error, when I click the plus button the value of the price turned to zero.

I have an html table then the value of the cell is write on php.

```
<td style="display: none;"><?php echo $row['PRODUCT_ID']; ?></td>
<td style="display: none;">
<?php
    $number = $row['PRODUCT_ID'];
    echo str_pad($number, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
?> 
</td>

<td> <img class="img-fluid" widht="100" height="100" src="img/product_images/<?php echo $row['PRODUCT_PICTURE']; ?>"></td>

<td>
<?php echo $row['PRODUCT_BRANDNAME'] . ' (' . $row['PRODUCT_DOSAGE'] . ') ' . $row['PRODUCT_FORM']; 
?> 
<br>
<?php echo $row['PRODUCT_GENERIC_NAME'] ?>
</td>


<td><?php echo $row['PRODUCT_QTY'];  ?></td>
<td style="display: none;">
<?php
if ($row['PRODUCT_QTY'] == 0) {
    echo  "";
} else {
    echo $row['PRODUCT_QTY'];
}
?>
</td>

<td style="display: none;"><?php echo $row['PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICE'] ?></td>
<td>
    <button data-id='<?php echo $row['PRODUCT_ID']; ?>' class="userinfo btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-list-alt"></i>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success bg-gradient-success editsbtnr" id="editsbtn" onclick="topFunction()" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-whatever="@mdo">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </button>

</td>
```

I will get the value of selling price and pass it on to the javascript and the javascript will  store it to the html element span

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.editsbtnr').on('click', function() {
        $('.adjust').show();
        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = $tr.children("td").map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        console.log(data);
        $('#id').val(data[0]);
        $('#name').val(data[3]);
        $("#quantity").attr("min", 1).attr("max", data[5]).attr('title', 'Must be greater than zero');

        document.getElementById("price").innerText = data[6];
    });
});
```

this is HTML code where the value of the selling price will appear

```
<div  class="adjust">
    <div class="quantity">
        <button class="btn minus-btn disabled" type="button">-</button>
        <input type="nnumber" id="quantity" value="1">
        <button class="btn plus-btn" type="button">+</button>
    </div>
    <!--will calculate price---->
    <p class="total-price">
        <span><i class="fa fa-ruby"></i></span>
    <span id="price"></span>
    </p>
</div>




**<script>
    //setting default attribute to disabled of minus button
    document.querySelector(".minus-btn").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    //taking value to increment decrement input value
    var valueCount
    //taking price value in variable
    var price = document.getElementById("price").innerText;
    //price calculation function
    function priceTotal() {
        var total = valueCount * price;
        document.getElementById("price").innerText = total
    }
    //plus button
    document.querySelector(".plus-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        //getting value of input
        valueCount = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        //input value increment by 1
        valueCount++;
        //setting increment input value
        document.getElementById("quantity").value = valueCount;
        if (valueCount > 1) {
            document.querySelector(".minus-btn").removeAttribute("disabled");
            document.querySelector(".minus-btn").classList.remove("disabled")
        }
        //calling price function
        priceTotal()
    })
    //plus button
    document.querySelector(".minus-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        //getting value of input
        valueCount = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        //input value increment by 1
        valueCount--;
        //setting increment input value
        document.getElementById("quantity").value = valueCount
        if (valueCount == 1) {
            document.querySelector(".minus-btn").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
        }
        //calling price function
        priceTotal()
    })
</script>**
```

Comment: What is the value of data ?  (as you have the line console.log(data);)

Comment: It seems that you have no function when click plus button but you have either  inline onclick attribute to call topFunction() and the listener in your jquery script for the same  editsbtn button. Is there a problem?

Comment: @KenLee the value of data is the selling price that was displayed on the table

Comment: @Stefino76 please dont mind the topfunction . It just to scroll up when the table has so many records

Comment: Ok, but I don't see in your code the function called when the plus button is clicked. Have you add a listener somewhere? And what about the function for add quantity and update price?

Comment: @Stefino76 im sorry I updated the code

Comment: You have var price = document.getElementById("price").innerText; inside your script tag. This code is executed when you load the page but you fill the span id="price" by jquery on document.ready, so you read price value before you fill it with the value. Try to move your var price = document.getElementById("price").innerText; inside priceTotal() function.